# What is the workflow for using scssphp?

Tags: php, sass

I'm trying to migrate my css over to scss for a PHP application, but I'm confused about the proper workflow for generating css files. I'm using [scssphp](http://leafo.net/scssphp/), which is a compiler for scss written in PHP.

In all my pages, I use the following stylesheet: `css/mycss.css`. I've put the `scss` version of the stylesheet in `css/scss/mycss.scss`. When I make changes to the scss file, I compile it locally by entering into my browser:

```
localhost/mywebsite/style.php/mycss.scss
```

The `style.php` file is as follows:

```
require "vendor/leafo/scssphp/scss.inc.php";
$scss = new scssc();
$directory = "css/scss";
$server = new scss_server($directory,null,$scss);
$server->serve();
```

This compiles the scss file and writes it to the `css/scss/scss_cache` folder. The filename is some hash. Here is my resulting directory structure:

```
style.php
-css
 mycss.css
    -scss
     mycss.scss
        -scss_cache
         4edf7f7bf9238jdsk9281sjkj32.css
```

Now ideally, I would like for the compiler to overwrite the `css/mycss.css` file. Is there a way to do this, or what's a proper workflow for replacing the original css file with the newly compiled css? I could always just copy and paste every time, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: what keeps you from compiling it locally with [sass](http://sass-lang.com/install)?

Comment: I could do that by installing ruby and associated gem, but I'd rather keep it php. And lots of php developers seem to use scssphp, so I'm wondering how they do it.

Comment: @shimizu i still write css by hand. sass/scss result in to many duplicate, rule and bloated file size

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`scssphp` is meant to be used to serve the stylesheets directly. But if you'd like to just use the compiler functionality, you can do that:

```
require "vendor/leafo/scssphp/scss.inc.php";
$scss = new scssc();

$scssIn = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/css/scss/mycss.scss');
$cssOut = $scss->compile($scssIn);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/css/mycss.css', $cssOut);
```

See http://leafo.net/scssphp/.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to replace `css/mycss.css` with `mywebsite/style.php/mycss.scss` in all your pages.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mywebsite/style.php/mycss.scss">
```

scssphp will now try to read mycss.css from its cache or compile it.

but I don't think that's be best way to work with scss. I recommend using one of the official [sass programms](http://sass-lang.com/install) or event [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to automate things.